# is it possible to concat 2 regular expression strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I have 2 regex strings in javascript and I need to concat them into 1 regex. I saw somewhere this could be done using |

example:

```
passwordRegex:RegExp = '(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*#?&^])[A-Za-z\\d$@$!%*#?&^]{8,}';
hasFourConsecutiveRegex:RegExp  = '(.)\\1\\1\\1';
combinedRegex:RegExp = new RegExp(this.passwordRegex.source  + ' | ' + this.hasFourConsecutiveRegex.source );
```

is this how its done?

Comment: Have you maybe tried if that's *how its done*? Wouldn't that answer your question?

Comment: Can you not just run it yourself and see what happens?

Comment: It depends what your reasons are for concatenating the expressions. What you have done is essentially create an or. Either it matches `passwordRegex` or (`|`) it matches `hasFourConsecutiveRegex`.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Validate an 8+ char string that contains at least one ASCII letter, one digit, one special char from the defined set **and** that has 4 identical consecutive chars?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
var passwordRegex = new RegExp('(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*#?&^])[A-Za-z\\d$@$!%*#?&^]{8,}');
var hasFourConsecutiveRegex = new RegExp('(.)\\1\\1\\1'); 
var combinedRegex = new RegExp(passwordRegex.source   + ' | ' + hasFourConsecutiveRegex.source  );
```

Comment: @TKDev, please accept this answer if it work for you.